# Running the same command in all windows of the unix terminal

Tags: bash, unix, ssh, terminal

Is there a way to run a single command in all the terminal windows you have open? (I.e. SSHing into a server or something like that?)

Comment: [Here](http://mtyurt.net/running-the-same-command-on-multiple-terminals-simultaneously-in-unix/) is an example answer to your question with tmux.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here are 2 tools that I use almost daily for this exact task:

[ClusterSSH](http://sourceforge.net/projects/clusterssh/) - Cross-platform (with X11 forwarding)

[image]

And [PuTTY Connection Manager](http://puttycm.free.fr/cms) (Windows)

[image]

Comment: WinSSHTerm is a big WOW! https://winsshterm.blogspot.co.il/

Answer (score 4):

You could use an intermediate tool such as chown has suggested ([ClusterSSH](http://sourceforge.net/projects/clusterssh/), [PuTTY Connection Manager](http://puttycm.free.fr/cms)), or some kind of macro software.

If **instead** you want to run the same set of commands across multiple machines, there are configuration management tools such as [Puppet](http://puppetlabs.com/) (and others) that will help you do this.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure how to do precisely what you're asking, but you might have a look at [dsh](http://www.netfort.gr.jp/~dancer/software/dsh.html) which lets you send commands to multiple shells at the same time.